# How to save Visual Basic button change made during debug execution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I would like to know if it's possible to save an edit button.text after stopping the program, so that when I start it again it has the new button.text there.

I'm changing a button.text that by default (when the program is launched) is snacks1. When I change this to snacks2 (debugg), it remains while the program is in progress, but as soon as I close the program it changes back to snacks1. Is there any way to save the button.text=snacks2 when the change is done while the program is running?

Hope I've been specific enough.

Comment: Are you aware of [My.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx)?

Comment: Well, i'm not. I'm still new to this, sorry. I'll check that now and learn it. Thanks for your atention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely you should learn about "My.Settings".

1. Through Project Tab you open Project properties.
2. Then in Settings tab you create an appropriate variable(for example Name = MyButtonText, Type = String, Scope = User, Value = snacks1). 
   [image: Settings tab after adding "MyButtonText"]
3. Making the assumption that you button is Named ButtonSnacks and you change its button.text from "snacks1" to "snacks2" through another button's(ButtonChange) Button_Click event, you should write something like the following:

`Private Sub ButtonChange_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonChange.Click
        My.Settings.MyButtonText = "snacks2"
        My.Settings.Save()
        ButtonSnacks.Text = My.Settings.MyButtonText
    End Sub`

4. At last you should change the Form_Load event in order to persist the change.

`Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ButtonSnacks.Text = My.Settings.MyButtonText
End Sub`

As a guideline I used this  [link](http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/persisting-the-values-of-controls-on-your-form/) whitch I find very helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, you want to make it save the data and
use it the next time you debug?

I would do it like this:

Go to Properies and then Settings and add ex. buttonText
Then go to your code and write something like this:

```
my.settings.buttonText = "TEXT HERE"
```

Then make it so when the form is started, write something like this:

```
button1.text = my.settings.buttonText
```